# Azure Pipeline: Accessing specific directory/files within a self-hosted agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm working on a powershell pipeline that creates a config file, along with other files/variables as parameters, that will be used to run an executable file. The executable file is located in the C:\temp\app\file.exe folder of the self-hosted agent that I'm using for the pipeline.

Once the files are in place I need to call the execute the file as -->
.\file.exe C:\paramfile

My question is, it is possible to put all those variables in the temp folder and then execute the file or do I need to load all the kit into the repo?
This is something I've never done it before, I usually call my scripts from an Azure Repo, call the Invoke-AzVMRunCommand and pass the variables as parameters during the pipeline run time.

Comment: I think you're approaching this the wrong way. If you need something on your agent as part of a pipeline, your pipeline should be responsible for retrieving from, say, Azure Artifacts.